# ComboBox.SelectedValue not working

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

What is wrong with this code?

```
myComboBox.Items.Clear();
myComboBox.Items.AddRange(new string[]{"one","two"});
myComboBox.SelectedValue = "one";
```

It is showing up with nothing selected.

Comment: Asp.net, win forms, wpf?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you populate the combobox like this:

```
myComboBox.Items.AddRange(new string[]{"one","two"});
```

You must use the [`ComboBox.SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or the [`ComboBox.SelectedIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to set/get the selected item:

```
myComboBox.SelectedItem = "one"; //or
myComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

---

> The [`ComboBox.SelectedValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property is inherited from
> `ListControl` and must be used **ONLY** when:
>
> - the control is bound to a `DataSource`
> - and `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` properties are definied.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of different options:

1) change `SelectedValue` to `SelectedIndex`

```
myComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0; //your first item
```

---

Please ignore this, this is for asp.net

2) add in `ListItem`s manualy

```
myComboBox.Items.Clear();
myComboBox.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = "one", Selected = true };
myComboBox.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = "two" };
```

Just make sure you don't have more than one item selected at a given time.