# Programmatically change SelectedValue ComboBox

Tags: vb.net

I am populating a combobox by connecting a datasource from an sql statement.

```
dt = select Name as [Name], Code as [Id] from Table
```

Then I want to se the default value of the combobox to "Nick" which I am locating with the following code

```
    For Each i as DataRowView in comboBox.Items

    If i("Name").ToString="Nick" Then
    comboBox.SelectedIndex=selectedCount
    Exit For
    End If

selectedCount=selectedCount +1
Next
```

This will correctly display "Nick" as the default in the comboBox, but when I go and get the selectedValue with the following code it is getting the selected index of the first item in the list not the delfault item "Nick".

When I click a button and look at the SelectedIndex of the combobox it is set back to 0 eventhough it displays the correct selectedValue in the comboxbox.

```
item=comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString
```

How do I get the selected Value I defaulted the combobox to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ComboBox.SelectedValue not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730262/combobox-selectedvalue-not-working).  Note quite the same, but I'd certainly look at using `SelectedItem` instead.

Comment: Can't you use `comboBox.SelectedItem = i`? BTW, don't forget to close the quotation mark after "Nick".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
item = comboBox.Items(comboBox.SelectedIndex).ToString
```

If your SelectedIndex somehow gets reverted back to 0, then declare an int and in your loop, set the ints value to the selectedCount. Then set the item by using the int as the comboBoxe's item index:

```
Dim index as Int = 0

For Each i as DataRowView in comboBox.Items

  If i("Name").ToString="Nick" Then
  comboBox.SelectedIndex=selectedCount
  index = selectedCount
  Exit For
  End If

  selectedCount=selectedCount +1
Next

item = comboBox.Items(index).ToString
```